# How to use await functions under readline.on functions in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

How can I use await function under `readline.on` function on nodejs
I'm trying to read each line using `readline.on` function and after reading each line from file, i'm trying to pass each line data to some other function which is an third party api so I have written promise for that function so calling that function using await under `readline.on` function, but its not returning result from that function. Can any one please help me to solve this one. Thanks in advance.

```
"use strict";
import yargs from 'yargs';
import fs from 'fs';
import redis from 'redis';
import path from 'path';
import readline from 'readline';

const args = yargs.argv;

// redis setup
const redisClient = redis.createClient();
const folderName = 'sample-data';

// list of files from data folder
let files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/' + folderName);

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
};

async function getContentFromEachFile(filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
    resolve(rl);
  });
};

async function readSeoDataFromEachFile() {
  await asyncForEach(files, async (file) => {
    let filePath = path.join(__dirname + '/' + folderName, file);
    let rl = await getContentFromEachFile(filePath);

    rl.on('line', async (line) => {
      let data = performSeoDataSetUpProcess(line);

      console.log(JSON.stringify(data.obj));

      let result = await getResultsFromRedisUsingKey(data.obj.name);

      console.log("result" + JSON.stringify(result));

    });
  });
};


async function getResultsFromRedisUsingKey(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    redisClient.get(key, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        resolve(err);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
};

readSeoDataFromEachFile();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your function `asyncForEach` and the callback of your `asyncForEach` call in `getContentFromEachFile` don't return a promise so you can't use it with async/await functions.

Async/await is not required for `getContentFromEachFile()`

As a result, I would do :

```
function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let result = []
    array.forEach((file, index, files) => {
      // concat the callback returned array of each file into the result
      const res = await callback(file, index, files);
      result = result.concat(res);
    });
    return resolve(result);
  });
};

function getContentFromEachFile(filePath) {
  return readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });
};

async function readSeoDataFromEachFile() {
  return await asyncForEach(files, (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const filePath = path.join(__dirname + '/' + folderName, file);
      let callbackResult = [];
      const rl = getContentFromEachFile(filePath);

      rl.on('line', async (line) => {
        let data = performSeoDataSetUpProcess(line);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.obj));

        // add the result from redis into the generated data
        data.redisResult = await getResultsFromRedisUsingKey(data.obj.name);
        console.log("result" + JSON.stringify(data.redisResult));

        // store the result in the local variable
        callbackResult.push(data);
      });

      rl.on('close', () => {
        // finally return the stored result for this file
        return resolve(callbackResult);
      });
    });
  });
};

console.log(readSeoDataFromEachFile());
```

Comment: getContentFromEachFile function returning each file content but  problem is not able to call getResultsFromRedisUsingKey result from this function

Comment: Are you sure `getResultsFromRedisUsingKey()` function returns a promise ?

Comment: Sorry i did not added getResultsFromRedisUsingKey function on question, Now i have added Please check once again question.

Comment: What is logged on `data.obj` and `result` ?

Comment: data = { obj : {"c":"CTHOMPSON , PCUL - CCLDC, DELIO ","index":"1","name":"c","value":"CTHOMPSON , PCUL - CCLDC, DELIO "} } and result = [{ "a": "ATHOMPSON , PAUL - AALBA, DELIO ", "index": "1", "name": "a", "value": "ATHOMPSON , PAUL - AALBA, DELIO " }];

Comment: @venukumar you have a result, I don't understand what's wrong with that, maybe I misunderstood your question... Do you mean you want to use the results after `readSeoDataFromFile()` call ?

Comment: yes i want to use result in some other function but for every line if i call getResultsFromRedisUsingKey function its not returning results instantly after reading all lines then its calling getResultsFromRedisUsingKey function.

Comment: Actually i want to use await function under rl.on('line', async (line) => {
        console.log('line' + line);
        await performSeoDataSetUpProcess(line);
      });   like this because for every line data i need to passs it to other function to get data from database ?

Comment: @venukumar please, check my edit, doesn't it answer to your question ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @dun32 but still getting error at line   result = result.concat(await callback(file, index, files));  getting error as   await is a reserved word

Comment: Please, check my new edit : store the callback result in a variable

Comment: Thanks @dun32 you helpped me a lot